# Compute weak formulation of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am learning finite element method and I would like to compute the weak formulation of the following problem:

$-\nabla^2u + u = f$

with the boundary conditions $u=u_0$ (Dirichlet) and $\nabla u \cdot n=g$. I am able to write the weak formulation of the Poisson equation and I did this:

$-\int_\Omega (\nabla^2 u)v \,d \Omega +\int_\Omega uv\,d \Omega = \int_\Omega fv\,d \Omega$.

Is this correct? I know that the first term in the LHS can be further "simplified" as in the Poisson equation, but I want to be sure that the second term in the LHS is correct.
Thank you.

Comment: Why are there minus signs on the lhs? What you have written should amount to multiplying the PDE with a function $v$ living in a certain space (which space?) and integrating over $\Omega$.

Comment: Also note that without specifying the function spaces of $u,v$ this can not be considered as a proper weak formulation.

Comment: Sorry, I modified the PDE.

Comment: Okay, now the first step is okay. It's still not a weak formulation, though. Try fully defining what a weak solution of the problem is.

Comment: Yes, I know that the solution is not that, I still have to "modify" the first term (but this is the same thing that I did for the Poisson equation). The professor did not say anything about "specifying the function spaces of $u,v$", though.

Comment: without specifying the function spaces, how do you define what a weak solution is?

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot understand that, the professor briefly derived the weak formulation of the Poisson equation and at the end said "how do we chose $v$?", but did not say anything more... Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: What @user159517 is referring to is that the weak formulation of the problem us usually of the form: Find $u \in X$ such that $\forall v \in Y$ it holds:
$- \int_\Omega v (\nabla^2 u \mathrm + u) \mathrm d x = \int_\Omega f v \mathrm d x$